# Getting the error "play-iteratees_2.10 not found" after adding the reactivemongo

Tags: scala, sbt, reactivemongo

I've started to learn reactivemongo by creating a simple Scala project. I started with SBT. Here is my `build.sbt` file:

```
name := "mongo-test"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.2"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.reactivemongo" %% "reactivemongo" % "0.9"
)
```

But I get the error when executing the compile command:

```
[info] Resolving play#play-iteratees_2.10;2.1.0 ...
[warn]  module not found: play#play-iteratees_2.10;2.1.0
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/amir/.ivy2/local/play/play-iteratees_2.10/2.1.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/play/play-iteratees_2.10/2.1.0/play-iteratees_2.10-2.1.0.pom
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: play#play-iteratees_2.10;2.1.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

UPDATE:
My SBT version is 0.13.0.

Comment: Which SBT version do you use?

Comment: @Schleichardt - 0.13.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add to your `build.sbt` this line:

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository releases" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
```

Comment: Would you please explain how did you find the solution?

Comment: On git repo readme. It should be also on the official webpage, but is not. :S https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/ReactiveMongo#set-up-your-project-dependencies